# How to export an ods table from jabref without messing it up?

Tags: tables, jabref, excel

I'm using jabref to manage my references.
The inssue that I'm facing is that I want to export all the columns that I've added.
Like:
[image]

But when I opened the exportted file, that are some columns that are called:

[image]

I would like to export them all does anybody know if is it possible? And why it's happaning this?

PS: I'm using the export tool from jabref to HTML  going to : `file > export > export all entries` and choosing the libre office with the ods extention

Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JabRef Maintainer/Dev here. I took a brief look at the code, and it seems this is [hard-coded](https://github.com/JabRef/jabref/blob/bb011c9313367a28990ae213b3920fe6cd10d1dc/src/main/java/org/jabref/logic/exporter/OOCalcDatabase.java#L135-L140) and therefore cannot be chaged by the user. The code hasn't been modified in ages.
I, however, agree with you that it should be possible to export all fields.
Therefore, I suggest you create an [issue](https://github.com/JabRef/jabref/issues) at our bug tracker.

As a workaround, you can create a new [Custom exporter](https://docs.jabref.org/collaborative-work/export/customexports) on basis of the existing [csv exporter](https://github.com/JabRef/jabref/tree/main/src/main/resources/resource/layout/openoffice). There, you can easily modify and include the fields you want to have.

Comment: I've changed the code but now the `abstract` and the   `comment` is getting over the other columns.
The code is the following:

Comment: `... "\booktitle","\keywords","\chapter","\edition","\series","\format[Authors(LastFirst,FullName,Semicolon,Semicolon)]{\editor}","\publisher","\begin{reporttype}\reporttype\end{reporttype}","\howpublished","\institution","\organization","\school","\annote","\format[Replace(\n || \, , ;)]{\abstract}","\comment","\format[FileLink(pdf)]{\file}","\key"
 `

Comment: Did you add the new fields also to the begin.csv.layout (those define the columns)

Comment: Yes I did it. I solve it puting the elements in between the `{}` in jabref